# Is there a difference between [web-database] and [database]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I ran across [web-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-database) in a recent question. There's only 45 questions using the tag and it has no wiki or usage guidelines. I cannot tell why the [database] tag couldn't have been used instead of this one in the questions tagged with it.

Am I missing something? Is this tag useful?

Uraz suggested this might be for Web SQL Databases, but that already has a tag called [[web-sql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-sql).

Comment: I have a problem with the database tag... There's large amounts of hatred towards so-called "meta-tags" that aid searching, but [tag:database] has tens of thousands of questions and effectively means "persistent data storage", it's so broad it's useless. [tag:web-database] _could_ actually be more useful.

Comment: i think it means Web SQL Databases which were introduced with HTML5 see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: There are also Access [web databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff402351(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 9):

I'm willing to bet that there's a misunderstanding of "web databases" from the askers in this tag.  Case in point:

> Recently I am trying to create a java application which will access my web database.

The question is closed and should likely *stay* that way, so don't bother with it right now.

The likely confusion is that the OP very much meant "database", but is confused on how to access it via a web site.

It's worth perusing this tag to see if there's anything worth saving, but I feel like the tag should go.

**Note:**  If you do start editing tags, ***clean up everything else in the question!***  We're not going to see these questions again for a long, long while.

Comment: I agree with this assessment and would add that the two "web-database"s I thought of already have separate tags. The first was, as @HansUp mentioned, [tag:ms-access-web-app] and the other was [tag:google-fusion-tables] which is debatable as a web-*database* either way.