# Synonymize [webdb] and [web-sql]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Rationale:  [webdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdb)'s wiki.

> A web database is a database application designed to be managed and accessed through the Internet. Web database can use a local database file to show the formularies in a web interface and to store the data.
>
> Web Database is no longer in active maintenance.

Contrast with [web-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-sql)'s wiki (abridged):

> Web SQL Database is a SQL-based API allowing web
> browsers/extensions/apps to store structured data locally. It is based
> on SQLite and, in practice, has been implemented solely on SQLite.
>
> The API is currently supported by Google Chrome, Opera and Safari.
> But, The W3C has abandoned Web SQL in favor of Web Storage and the
> Indexed Database API. From the Web SQL spec [...]

Comment: I know you know this, but for reference: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315777/215552

Comment: Given that there are just ~30 questions in one of the tags, can you do a quick sweep through and make sure that they're all related to the other tag? If you confirm, I'll go ahead with the synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the 29 questions tagged [webdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdb):

- 22 questions, all from before 2013 were about [web-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-sql), the now deprecated WebSQL standard.
- 2 of the questions were about [Cordova WebSQL](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#websql)
- There was one question about [Polymer WebSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238358/using-browser-db-with-polymer)
- There was one question about [Oracle's WebDB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/webdb.817/a77075/basics.htm), which I retagged with [oracle-webdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-webdb).
- There were questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168911/webdb-update-problem) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560522/access-web-application-data-macro-to-sum-values-in-query-and-return-as-variable), which I had no idea which webdb it was about, so I left the tag as it is. If anyone knows about the tech for these 2 questions, please feel free to retag.

I then synonymized [webdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdb) to [websql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websql). That is [webdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdb) (× 28) → [web-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-sql) (× 812).