# Do database questions that include a DBMS product tag need a [database] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I have seen a lot of tag edits recently that added the [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) tag to questions already tagged with a database product (e.g. [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql), [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)) - obviously most of those questions are also tagged with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

I think the [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) tag adds nothing to those questions as it's obvious that a "database" is used by mentioning a database product name.

Does it make sense to remove the [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) tag in that situation?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315777/is-there-a-difference-between-web-database-and-database (with sensible comments about that tag)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) tag is almost as useless as [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and is only warranted for those questions that are truly database-agnostic and I don't expect to have many of those, specially not over 170K.

Adding such generic tags to a question that is already perfectly scoped with the product specific tag is not useful, I would even say it might harm those users that find their questions with tag searches and/or filters. There are only 5 slots available for tags, adding a more generic tag isn't a great way to categorize these questions.

Making tag edits to introduce the tag for the cases you describe should not be done. If it is found in the suggested-edits review queue the edit should be rejected (or maybe "improved" by removing that tag again if the rest of the edit is worth keeping), and if those questions pop-up in your active tab with those tags added, rollback. Try to inform the editor their re-tags are frowned upon and flag for a moderator if that doesn't workout as you hope for.

Comment: I find `database` entirely useless, but personally think the usage of `sql` still adds some value if the question is actually about SQL.

Answer (score -12):

It depends whether you think it is a database problem, or when you are not sure if it is SQL or database related, you also would use both tags, to get the people, who are interested.

A specific RDBMS is a absolutely **must have tag**, because the different types of RDBMS handle things differently.

Also a **must tag** is the version you use, because even in a RDBMS different version have other features, that could help.
The other thing is, if you have an older version of a RDBMS, that could explain the problem.

Comment: Well a question regarding a relational database is always a "database problem"

Comment: no, it can be a simple sql syyntax problem, and then it is tagged with mysql, but it has nothing to do with with the database in particular

Comment: MySQL **is** "a database" - so even for a simple syntax problem (tagged with `sql` and `mysql`) the database tag is completely useless and doesn't add anything.

Comment: yes mysql is a rdms, but a problem with stored procedires where the syntax is wrong , has nothing to do with the database it has to do with sql and stored procedures, so the valid tags a mysql,sql, stored procedure, the same goes fpr mysql Workbench, a problem there can be only mysql workbench related, ist is still tagged mysql , workbencn ans eer, this has also nothing to do with the database per se, You can look at my profile, almost all my tags are mysql related, but not all include database, the fakt is ist  is rarely related to the database

Comment: So you agree that the `database` tag is completely useless?

Comment: no, it is **needed**, so we can check if it is better suited to DBA instead of SO, because the line is gray in that area

Comment: So what additional information does the `database` tag convey that isn't covered by `sql` or a product specific tag?

Comment: databse refers to problems with the database engine or configuration, when  mysql doesn't give an error or warning, so that is it not a sql language error. like me we, decide if it is worth sending it to DBA, when the problem is not solved by look into the error log or something obvious. Things like Replication, Database design and so on, go usually to DBA. But as it is not off topic to ask about the database it is a valid and necessary tag

Comment: So if I have a problem with my Postgres or Oracle configuration and I add the `postgresql` or `oracle` tag, then what additional information does the `database` tag add to the question?

Comment: is tells the experienced user that is not a basic or complicated programming question, which i prefer, else it has something to do with oracle configuration or postgre configuration, and you will read often, you should ask it at DBA, which is the side for that, but as you noticed here, the people ask questions sometimes without knowing they are offtopic. When we are here, why can't we send  questions to more sites than 4 super user serverfault and codereview should also be send by bronze silver or gold member to the right subsite

Comment: You are assuming everyone uses the tag correctly  and doesn't just throw the tag on because databases are involved.

Comment: all user with bronze batch and higher and even without "correct" incorrect tags, so if something is tagged still database and is not moved, belogs to that tags and no i don't assume, that everybody uses the tag right, i explain where the difference is and why it is needed.